# Calling a function with the same name as a local variable

Tags: javascript, debugging, if-statement

I have the following code...

```
var firstPlay = 1;
if (firstPlay == 1) {
    firstPlay();
}
```

When I remove the if statement and just put

```
 firstPlay();
```

Then it works but with the if statement it doesn't.

Did I make a typo? If not how can I go about debugging this problem?

Comment: Is the above your code, all your code, exactly your code, and nothing but your code?

Comment: Its a small part of a 166 line piece of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting the variable `firstPlay` to the value 1, you can't run a value... use different names for your variables.

Such as:

```
var firstPlayTest = 1;
if (firstPlayTest == 1) { firstPlay(); }​
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured since functions and variables were different that they could have the same name without interfering.

Comment: @PhilipK: That's the thing, in JavaScript, they are *not* different.

Comment: @PhilipK Javascript uses plain old variables to store everything. You could just as well declare a function as follows: `var firstPlay = function(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

A previous function definition of function firstPlay() is replaced/redefined by the numerical value 1.
In the following code

```
        function firstPlay() {alert("firstPlay");}
        alert(firstPlay);
        var firstPlay = 1;
        alert(firstPlay);
```

the first alert shows a function definition while the second alert shows "1".